# Why is there a preference for selector.open() vs selector()?

Tags: java, constructor

In all examples I have seen a selector object is created via the `selector.open()` method as opposed to the `selector()` constructor. Why is this the case?

Comment: Selector is an abstract class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Selector` is an abstract class, so it can't be created directly via the constructor.

`Selector.open()` is there, so that you didn't have to bother with initializing a specific instance yourself (its type may depend on other factors, so It doesn't have to be the same class all the time) - it will do it for you.

Comment: Alright that makes sense, however I can't understand what is meant by the fact that each invocation of a jvm maintains a "single system-wide default provider instance".

Comment: It is because it may be implemented in different VMs/operating systems differently. I think you can initialize the provider directly if you know its concrete class but `Selector.open()` provides a safer way to do that.

Comment: Would it be correct to say the selector.open() method instantiates a service provider that is found in the java api that came with my JVM which implements the selectorprovider class. Once the service provider is instantiated the openselector() method is called.

Comment: @ABC123 If you have access to the sources you can look at the implementation. Also, the documentation of [`SelectorProvider.provider()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/spi/SelectorProvider.html#provider()) describes how it looks for an implementation.